# How to access 1 webcam with 2 threads

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video-capture

I am using python 3.5 with opencv.

I want to use 2 threads:

- Thread 1: Save the video to a file
- Thread 2: Display the video to the user

To view/capture the video from webcam i am using snippets of code from the following website: [opencv video docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

I can capture and save the video using the following code:

```
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
    else:
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can view the video using the following code:

```
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Each of these pieces of code are in their own functions called capture and display. I then call them in separate threads with pythons threading library as follows:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
Thread(target=capture).start()
Thread(target=display).start()
cap.release()
```

I get an error I assume is related to both threads wanting to access the video buffer at the same time.

I understand this can be done without threads but there are other things I would like to do further than can only be done in separate threads.

How can I access the cap video capture from both threads?

Comment: Why don't you wait until you have come to the "other things" and ask then?

Comment: @KlausD. I have come to that point, but I simplified my example down above.

Comment: What is the error? and what will you try to achieve, it could be that threads is not necessary? You will need a thread safe object, one that when you try to get a frame it has a mutex or something like that

Comment: @api55 My aim is to have one thread waiting for movement within the video, then record when there is movement. Then the other thread to simply view the video capture

Comment: I am about to go to sleep, but here goes: Create an object which has an updateFrame function which, in a thread safe manner updates an internal frame object. Then another function returns the current frame (again, in a thread safe manner) then you can connect all the threads you want to this object, and only one frame grabs a new frame. I can put an example tomorrow with more detail as an answer.

Comment: @api55 My plan would to eventually have the `VideoCapture` viewable in browser using a web framework (flask/django) with the motion recording/saving going on in the background. Would two threads be needed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My flask/django experience is increadibly limited, so I am not sure how to do it for that exactly, but I will answer the question posted directly.

First you need to create a thread-safe object to avoid calling at the same time the read function in different threads.

```
import cv2
import threading

class VideoCamera(object):
  # filename can be 0 to access the webcam
  def __init__(self, filename):
    self.lock = threading.Lock()
    self.openVideo(filename)

  def openVideo(self, filename):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.videoCap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
    self.lock.release()
```

With this, you should be able to create an object with a lock and to open safely a video (in case that you want to open another video with the same object).

Now you have 2 options, either you create a thread that updates the frame and stores the current one internally or update do in a thread safe manner the get next frame function. I will do the second one here to show you:

```
  def getNextFrame(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    img = None
    # if no video opened return None
    if self.videoCap.isOpened():
      ret, img = self.videoCap.read()
    self.lock.release()
    return img
```

This way you should be able to access the video cap with 2 frames... however, the frames will be different every time the function is called.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Helps a lot. Thanks very much

Comment: `ret, img = self.camVid.read()` should be `ret, img = self.videoCap.read()` based on the example above.