# How to get http stream from wifi camera compressed format: h.264 on python?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, h.264, ip-camera

Hy! I am working on a project for school using a HD-eyewear Wifi Camera that uses H.264 compressed format. I have read a lot of documentation about how to get the frames from the camera, but I shouldn't manage my problem. My code looks like this:

```
import cv2

while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:@192.168.10.1/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=') 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
```

I only want to see that it gets correctly the frames, but it drops errors like this:

```
[h264 @ 0x1e0a100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

[h264 @ 0x1e0a100] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

[h264 @ 0x1e0a100] decode_slice_header error

[h264 @ 0x1e0a100] no frame!
```

I really apreciate the help! Thanks! :D

Comment: Check to ensure your camera link is valid by opening up the stream in VLC player, if it works there, it should work with those links

Comment: Thank you! I will check these sources and I will leave a comment if it helps me! :D Also I checked the camera link and it's valid, works good.

Comment: Thamk you very much, I could manage my problem!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from comments, I could solve my problem, and works, with some initial frame loss.

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread
import time




url = ('http://admin:@192.168.10.1/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=')


class VideoStream(object):
    def __init__(self,url = ('http://admin:@192.168.10.1/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=')):
            self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
            self.thread.daemon = True
            self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
            while True:
                    if self.capture.isOpened():
                            (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
                    time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self):
            cv2.imshow('frame', self.frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                    self.capture.release()
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_stream = VideoStream()
    while True:
            try:
                    video_stream.show_frame()
            except AttributeError:
                    pass
```

Copied from this link: [Video Streaming from IP Camera in Python Using OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828451/video-streaming-from-ip-camera-in-python-using-opencv-cv2-videocapture/55838623)